# windows phone 8 bing map route drag and drop to change route path

Tags: windows-phone-8, bing-maps

heloo everyone, i am working on a app which is working perfect right now, i want to make more functionality so that when the map route is drawn from user current location to user specified location,it could be changed by user using tap, so user can have the ability to make another route for that place. currently i am using **BingMapsDirectionsTask** class to achieve all this

Answer (score 0):

That works just fine on WP8. After invoking BingMapsDirectionsTask/MapsDirectionsTask the map app will show the requested route, but users can then click the "Directions" arrow on the appbar or the "Search" icon on the appbar.

To answer the unspoken question, if you can't see the functionality you're looking for on a Task/Chooser class, it's not there.

Comment: i want to have multi route application, suppose user want to go from A to C, so there should be a Map route showing route path from A to B then C and Also A to C